# Pivotal GemFire 9.1.1: Replicated Region not created in cluster

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a GemFire cluster with 2 Locators and 2 Servers in two unix machines. I am running a Spring Boot app which joins the GemFire cluster as a peer and tries to create Replicated Regions, loading the Regions using Spring Data GemFire. Once the Spring Boot app terminates, I am not seeing the Region/data in cluster.

Am I missing something here?

GemFire cluster is not using `cache.xml` or Spring XML to bootstrap the Regions. My idea is to create Regions through a standalone program and make it available in the cluster. SDGF version is `2.0.7`.

gemfire-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
        <prop key="locators">unix_machine1[10334],unix_machine2[10334]</prop>
        <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="autoSerializer" class="org.apache.geode.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer">

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" pdx-serializer-ref="autoSerializer" pdx-read-serialized="true"/>

    <gfe:replicated-region id="Test" ignore-if-exists="true"/>

    <gfe:replicated-region id="xyz" ignore-if-exists="true"/>

</beans>
```

Expectation is when the Spring Boot app terminates, Region should be created in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach here would be to use Cluster Configuration Service, and create regions via gfsh. See the below link for more information

https://docs.spring.io/spring-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:cache:advanced

See the section 
Using Cluster-based Configuration

For more information on Cluster configuration please see the below link

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_persist.html

The your client code probably be a simple gemfire client connecting to the gemfire cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are not correct.  This is not a limitation with Spring per say, but is a side effect of how GemFire works.

If you were to configure a GemFire peer cache instance/member of the cluster using the [GemFire API](http://gemfire-97-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/) or pure [`cache.xml`](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/reference/topics/elements_ref.html), then the cluster would not "remember" the configuration either.

When using the GemFire API, `cache.xml` or Spring config (either Spring XML or JavaConfig), the configuration is local to the member.  Before GemFire's [*Cluster Configuration Service*](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_persist.html), administrators would need to distribute the configuration (e.g. `cache.xml`) across all the peer members that would form a cluster.

Then along came the *Cluster Configuration Service*, which enabled users to define their configuration using *Gfsh*.  In Spring config, when configuring/bootstrapping a peer cache member of the cluster, you can enable the use of cluster configuration to configure the member, for example:

```
<gfe:cache use-cluster-configuration="true" ... />
```

As was pointed out [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:cache:advanced) (bullet 4).

However, using *Gfsh* to configure each and every GemFire object (`Regions`, `Indexes`, `DiskStores`, etc) can be quite tedious, especially if you have a lot of Regions.  Plus, not all developer want to use a shell tool.  Some development teams want to version the config along with the app, which makes good sense.

Given you are using Spring Boot, you should have a look at ***Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire***, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode).

Another way to start your cluster is to configure and bootstrap the members using Spring, rather than *Gfsh*. I have example of this [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-cluster-configuration-bootstrapping).  You can, of course, run the Spring Boot app from the command-line using a Spring Boot FAT JAR.

Of course, some administrators/operators prevent development teams from bootstrapping the GemFire cluster in this manner and instead expect the teams to use the tools (e.g. *Gfsh*) provided by the database.

If this is your case, then it might be better to develop Spring Boot, GemFire `ClientCache` applications connecting to a standalone cluster that was started using *Gfsh*.

You can still do very minimal config, such as:

```
start locator --name=LocatorOne
start server --name=ServerOne
start server --name=ServerTwo
...
```

And then let your Spring Boot, client application drive the configuration (i.e. Regions, Indexes, etc) of the cluster using SDG's [cluster configuration push](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-cluster) feature.

There are many different options, so the choice is yours.  You need to decide which is best for your needs.

Hope this helps.